# Records not appearing on account dataTable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable

I am not able to pull any of the related records to the account dataTable. I want to see the related records for Trade_Lanes__c on the data table, but nothing shows up. Below is my code.

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountRelatedObj {
@auraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Trade_Lane__c> getContactsRelatedToAccount(String accId) {
    system.debug('accId >> ' + accId);
    return [SELECT Name, Annual_Ocean_Volume__c,Annual_Air_Volume_kg__c, Annual_Road_Volume_cbm__c from Trade_Lane__c where AccountId__c = :accId];
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LWC Record Id Example ">
        <lightning-datatable data={TradeLanes} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getContactsRelatedToAccount from 
'@salesforce/apex/AccountRelatedObj.getContactsRelatedToAccount';
export default class AccountRelatedContacts extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track TradeLanes;
    @track columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' },
        { label: 'Ocean Volume', fieldName: 'annual_ocean_volume__c' },
        { label: 'Air Volume', fieldName: 'annual_air_volume_kg__c'},
        { label: 'Road Volume', fieldName: 'annual_road_volume_cmb__c'},


        
    ];

    @wire(getContactsRelatedToAccount, {accId: '$recordId'}) 
    WireContactRecords({error, data}){
        if(data){
            this.contacts = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }else{
            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, here. First, you're assigning to `this.contacts`, which is the wrong variable. Secondly, JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. I suspect you're not seeing your data because the `fieldName` properties are all lowercase. You can, and should, import the field names to avoid case sensitivity problems.

As a side note, you're not translating the data in your wire handler, so you may as well just get rid of it.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from "lwc";
import getContactsRelatedToAccount from "@salesforce/apex/AccountRelatedObj.getContactsRelatedToAccount";
import TRADE_LANE_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Name";
import TRADE_LANE_ANNUAL_OCEAN_VOLUME from "@salesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Annual_Ocean_Volume__c";
import TRADE_LANE_ANNUAL_AIR_VOLUME_KG from "@salesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Annual_Air_Volume_KG__c";
import TRADE_LANE_ANNUAL_ROAD_VOLUME_CMB from "@salesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Annual_ROAD_Volume_CMB__c";

export default class AccountRelatedContacts extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  columns = [
    { label: "Name", fieldName: TRADE_LANE_NAME.fieldApiName },
    {
      label: "Ocean Volume",
      fieldName: TRADE_LANE_ANNUAL_OCEAN_VOLUME.fieldApiName,
    },
    {
      label: "Air Volume",
      fieldName: TRADE_LANE_ANNUAL_AIR_VOLUME_KG.fieldApiName,
    },
    {
      label: "Road Volume",
      fieldName: TRADE_LANE_ANNUAL_ROAD_VOLUME_CMB.fieldApiName,
    },
  ];
  @wire(getContactsRelatedToAccount, { accId: "$recordId" }) TradeLanes;
}
```

Comment: Now seeing this error: 
 "message": "Exception while getting the LWC bundle for reference @ssalesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Annual_ROAD_Volume_CMB__c of type module in file contactsonAccount.js\nException while getting the LWC bundle for reference @ssalesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Annual_Ocean_Volume__c of type module in file contactsonAccount.js\nException while getting the LWC bundle for reference @ssalesforce/schema/Trade_Lane__c.Annual_Air_Volume_KG__c of type module in file contactsonAccount.js",

Comment: @AshmitaKohli Yeah, for some reason, an extra 's' snuck in 'salesforce'. It should be `@salesforce/schema/Object_Name__c.Field_Name__c`. I've edited this.

Comment: thanks for this! I am able to load the table into Salesforce, but no records are showing. I have added a picture to my original post. I am thinking it has to do with my controller, but I am not sure. Could it be the Account ID does not have as many digits?

Comment: @AshmitaKohli Oh, I forgot. Since we got rid of the intermediate variable, we need to update our HTML, too: `<lightning-datatable data={TradeLanes.data} columns={columns} key-field="Id">`

Comment: Updated, but getting an error in Salesforce now. Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')] Line 4, column 342. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @AshmitaKohli adding `if:true={TradeLanes}` to your `lightning-datatable` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a surrounding div that checks if your collection variable was initialized. Sometimes the LWC renders stuff faster than they are retrieved from backend.

```
<div if:true={TradeLanes}>
    <lightning-card title="LWC Record Id Example ">
        <lightning-datatable data={TradeLanes} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</div>
```

Comment: LWC always renders faster than the data is retrieved from the backend. You can use the `is-loading` to display a loading animation before the data is available. You do not need to have the data available on initial render.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it running by making sure "TradeLanes.data" was capitalized. .

Comment: instead of posting your answer, consider accepting the one that actually pointed you towards fixing your code. since javascript is CaSe sEnSiTiVe...

Answer (score -1):

@Ashmita Kohli,

You need to update the code as below:

```
@wire(getContactsRelatedToAccount, {accId: '$recordId'}) 
    WireContactRecords({error, data}){
        if(data){
            this.TradeLanes = data; //instead of contacts you need to have TradeLanes
            this.error = undefined;
        }else{
            this.error = error;
            this.TradeLanes = undefined;//instead of contacts you need to have TradeLanes
        }
    }
```

Comment: I made the updates you suggested, but the records are still not pulling through